# Add images to the UITextFields at particular position in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am creating an iOS application in that i need to add image at particular position (top-left), How should i add the image to the Text Field at particular position?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Jon Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIImageView* usernameIconImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 42, 42)];
    usernameIconImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"username.jpg"];
    UIView* usernameIconContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 42, 42)];
    usernameIconContainer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.9 alpha:1.0];
    [usernameIconContainer addSubview:usernameIconImage];

    self.userIDField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    self.userIDField.leftView = usernameIconContainer;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Add ImageView as leftView in UITextField

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage"]];
[textField setLeftView:imageView];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `UITextField` `leftView` property, where you can easily assign an `UIImageView` see code below.

```
self.textField.leftViewMode=UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 30.0)];
imageView.image=YOURIMAGE;
self.textField.rightView=imageView;
```

I hope it helps.

Cheers.

Comment: I hope you meant `self.textField.leftView = imageView;`

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImageView *leftImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, self.yourTextField.frame.size.height)]; // you can choose your desired width
        [leftImageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [leftImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"]];
        yourTextField.leftView = leftImageView;
```